# Firebase InstanceID: does it persist after app uninstall/reinstall?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

In case of uninstalling the app and reinstalling after a few weeks, does the Firebase InstanceID stay the same or a new one gets generated?

Comment: Which client SDK?  For Android, it's clear from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) that a new instance ID is generated.  Probably the same for iOS.